# Integrating SIMBL with my application?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, installation

I have an application that uses SIMBL. I know that there's a installer available on their website but how can I install it manually? In other words, without the user knowing. What files will I have to place and where?

Answer (score 3):

I very much hope that there is no way that the SIMBL installer could be run without the user knowing (but I'm pretty sure that is not the case).  Certainly, if I were to discover that SIMBL had been installed behind my back, I would hunt down the guilty app, nuke it from my system and then publicly point out that it is doing so.

Don't get me wrong;  SIMBL is neat stuff.  It is also wickedly dangerous.  It modifies applications in ways that cannot possibly be supported and, thus, are exceedingly fragile.   As much as I've enjoyed hacking around with such tools, I cannot abide by that level of indeterminate fragility on any system I rely upon.

I.e. tell the user that you are going to install SIMBL, open the package in the Installer, and let the user do so or decline.  Do *not* do this behind their back.